# SQL Access Order By Time (same time stamp) changes order of events based on name

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have an issue when sorting by time. I have a DB (using access DB) where some entries have exact same time (even seconds). When I sort the events by time, the table sorts the records by time first, then organizes them based on the first letter of the next column.

```
'Select * FROM Events Where RunNo = ' + RunNo + ' ORDER By Time'

RunNo  Time      Expination
1    6:23:29AM  Installing
1    6:23:29AM  Doing Something
```

What's happening is, in my report that I generate with the above query prints "Doing Something" appears before "Installing" even though "Installing" is first in my DB. How do I make my Order By Time not change the sequence but keep the sequence and continue to sort the other but chronological order?

Comment: This is where an id column would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *Access*, you can use *Switch* for this:

```
'Select * From Events Where RunNo = ' + RunNo + ' ORDER By Time, Switch([Expination] = "Installing", 0, [Expination] = "Doing Something", 1, [Expination] = "Ready for use", 2)'
```

Comment: Ended up using a switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

`ORDER BY` in SQL (in general) is not *stable*.  That means that rows with the same key values can be in an arbitrary order -- and it could even change from one run to the next.

The general solution is to use a unique id on the row -- and identity column or creation date.  Then you can do:

```
ORDER BY Time, id
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.   the project never had an ID, so i don't have this option available.  How about Order By with a clause?  I've been even trying to compare the first value of the row. to the next to see if they're different letters.